# How to use a maven plugin from leiningen

Tags: clojure, jruby, compass-sass, leiningen

The specific plugin I want to be able to use is the [jruby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/torquebox/jruby-maven-plugins) so I can easily use compass in a clojure project.

If it's not possible to use maven plugins, what would be the best strategy to use a ruby gem in a clojure project?

Answer (score 1):

The following two projects provide ruby gem support.
[lein-ruby](https://clojars.org/lein-ruby)
[clogems](https://clojars.org/clogems)

clogems project does not have anything in the way of documentation, so you are probably on your own with that.

lein-ruby provides some documentation on it's [github](https://github.com/mental/lein-ruby) page. From the github page for lein-ruby.

### Usage

#### Tasks

This plugin adds one task to Leiningen:

- `lein ruby CMD [ARGS...]` - runs a Ruby command

You are responsible for adding the desired version of jruby-complete
to your project's dependencies.

#### Hooks

The plugin also includes a set of hooks (in the `leiningen.ruby.bundler`
namespace) which accomplish three things:

- augment `lein deps` to install bundler and any gems specified in
  your project's Gemfile into `vendor/gems`
- add `vendor/gems` to your project's classpath
- package the gems in `vendor/gems` as part of your project's jar

#### Options

lein-ruby also introduces two options which can be set in your project.clj:

- `:ruby-version` - the Ruby version to use for `lein ruby`: "1.8" or "1.9" (default)
- `:ruby-gem-dir` - the directory to use for gems, relative to the project root (defaults to `vendor/gems`)

Comment: I tried to improve the answer with some more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is possible to use Mavern plugins and dependancies. Looking at Leiningen's [GitHub](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#overview), I found the following pieces of information that seem relevant:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
               [clj-http "2.0.0"]]
```

> Leiningen will automatically download the clj-http jar and make sure it is on your classpath.

...

> Leiningen reuses existing JVM repository infrastructure. There are several popular open source repositories. Leiningen by default will use two of them: clojars.org and Maven Central.
>
> You can add third-party repositories by setting the :repositories key in project.clj. See the [sample.project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj) for examples on how to do so.